# Error with specifyModel

Tags: r, time-series, xts, quantmod

I'm facing this problem and can't solve it :
Here is the code :

```
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)
library(randomForest)


getSymbols('^STOXX50E', src='yahoo')
equity.index<-STOXX50E

myReturnsSign = function(x) sign(Delt(Cl(x),type="log"))[-1]
mySMA =function(x,n) SMA(Cl(x),n)[-1]
myEMA = function(x,n,ratio) EMA(Cl(x),n,ratio)[-1]



model1<-specifyModel(myReturnsSign(equity.index) ~ myEMA(equity.index,20,0.8) + mySMA    (equity.index,5))
```

Here is the error message :

```
Error in xts(model.frame(model@model.spec, data = env, na.action = NULL),  : 
NROW(x) must match length(order.by)
```

However :

```
> dim(myEMA(equity.index,20,0.8))
[1] 2632    1

> dim(mySMA(equity.index,5))
[1] 2632    1

> dim(myReturnsSign(equity.index))
[1] 2632    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, the `specifyModel` code hasn't been worked on in over 4 years, and I don't think that is because it is stable.

Without looking too closely, it looks like your problem can be solved by removing those `[-1]` subsets from your functions

```
myReturnsSign = function(x) sign(Delt(Cl(x),type="log"))
mySMA =function(x,n) SMA(Cl(x),n)
myEMA = function(x,n,ratio) EMA(Cl(x),n,ratio)
model1<-specifyModel(myReturnsSign(equity.index) ~ myEMA(equity.index,20,0.8) + mySMA(equity.index,5))
```

Comment: Infact, it works. I don't understand why the `[-1]`in my functions is problematic. I put it in order to get rid of the first value of the returns whcih is `Na`.

Comment: I'm not really sure either.  But, as I mentioned, I think this code was sort of abandoned.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answers GSee. I was using `specifyModel` with the intention of building a Random Forest. Do you advice me so to use directly the `randomForest`function?

Comment: I don't see what one has to do with the other.  If you want to use `randomForest`, don't bother with `specifyModel`